# How to apply limit and offset in fetching list through Spring Jdbc Template on MySql DB

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbctemplate

Need to apply limit and offset on the select query using jdbc template on MySql DB.

```
String query = "SELECT *from loaquesform F inner join loainfo N inner join loa_approval A on F.loaId = N.loaId and N.loaId = A.loaId where loaStatus IN (?) LIMIT ?, ? order by loaId desc;"

LoaFormList = userJdbcTemplateMysql.query(query,
                            new BeanPropertyRowMapper(LoaFormWithSrv.class),
                            new Object[]{loaStatusCriteria.getLoaStatus(),loaStatusCriteria.getLimit(), 
                                loaStatusCriteria.getOffset()});
```

I am calling this program with limit and offset =10

I am getting below error-

```
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near ''10', '10' order by loaId desc' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` [needs to be preceded](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) by the `LIMIT` clause:

```
String query = 
   "SELECT * from loaquesform F inner join loainfo N inner join loa_approval A on F.loaId = N.loaId and N.loaId = A.loaId where loaStatus IN (?) order by loaId desc LIMIT ?, ?;"
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''10', '10'' at line 1

Comment: JDBCTemplate is inserting quotes around the limit parameters. Are `loaStatusCriteria.getLimit()` and `loaStatusCriteria.getOffset()` numeric types?